# How to make one part of header text different font and add dashes around whole header text?

Tags: html, css, inline, bold

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

To start that design I would like first to create one part of header text bold(using different font), how can i accomplish this?

Currently this spawns my header title:

```
 <h2 class="h1  section-header--left" style="font-family: Geogrotesque Regular; color: #071435; font-size: 22px">MEEST POPULAIR</h2>
```

To make text bold I use font "Geogrotesque SemiBold", does anyone know how I can add this css in html line and create the design I want? So text "Meest" should be font "Geogrotesque Regular" and text "Populair" should be font "Geogrotesque SemiBold".

Would be nice if you know css to create dashes around header to.

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple example with other font:

```css
h2 {
font: 33px sans-serif;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2.background {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

 h2.background:before{
    border-top: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    content:"";
    margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
    position: absolute; /* positioning must be absolute here, and relative positioning must be applied to the parent */
    top: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 95%;
    z-index: -1;
}


span { 
    /* to hide the lines from behind the text, you have to set the background color the same as the container */ 
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family:arial;
}


h2.double:before { 
/* this is just to undo the :before styling from above */
border-top: none; 
}

h2.double:after {
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
content: "";
margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the line to the full width specified */
position: absolute;
top: 45%; left: 0; right: 0;
width: 95%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="background double"><span style='font-family: Geogrotesque Regular!important;' >FIRST</span><span style='font-family: cursive!important;'>TWO</span></h2>
```

Comment: Do you know how to add dashes to?

Comment: When i use <em> it makes the font italic without me saying it anywhere? I just want to apply different font, not styles.

Comment: use css for change you font/style, you add my css?

Comment: Im using <span> item now with css .bold-text{Font-family: other}

Comment: I just need to know dashes now

Comment: i change my code with dashes to, acept answer and upvote thanks

Comment: Hi, it works but only the dashes are on full width of site, I would like to have same as on image in post.

Comment: adapt width of h2 or change width of dash. where is the problem?

Comment: All my other <span> with elements have #fff background now, how can i reset this and still to apply on what you made?

Comment: can you apple rule css directly on the span with style

Comment: Im new to this, but the css you written is applying on other elements on site to..If i remove ur css its all good again so we need custom names

Comment: Delete span{ code} to css i write, and add all voice of that directly to style of span

Comment: Oke, got it. How can i decrease widths of line now?

Comment: You can control width of all h2 with width:100px(example) or h2.double:after width

Comment: Hi, all the dashes have different sizes now, width of total div is for example 100px but if text is 90, lines will be 5 pixels each(left and right), is it possible to have all lines same width of div is different each time?